# How do I read <parameter> that is under <method> in TestNG XML?

Tags: xml, selenium, testng

I am trying to read and store the `<value>` of `<parameter>` which is under `<methods>` and `<class>`. I tried different ways to read the xml but I am not able to read the parameter value which is under methods and class.

I have tried 
`String parameterName = Reporter.getCurrentTestResult().getTestContext().getCurrentXmlTest().getParameter("name of the parameter");`
But there is no luck.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Test"  parallel="methods" configfailurepolicy="continue" 
data-provider-thread-count="5">
<parameter name="threads" value="5" />
<parameter name="environment" value="http://ghdajhsdgajh.com"/>
<parameter name="grid" value="false" />
<parameter name="token" value="54545455455545455455"/>
<parameter name="local" value="true" />

<test name="Woohoo">
    <classes>
        <class name="com...............">
            <methods>
                <parameter name="Phone" value="Iphone"/>
                <include name="testIphone"/>
            </methods>
        </class>
        <class name="com...............">
            <methods>
                <parameter name="phone" value="Samsung"/>
                <include name="testSamsung"/>
            </methods>
        </class>
```

How do I read and store method parameters i.e, "Iphone" and "Samsung"???

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample that shows how to get this value. FWIW, I am using the latest released version of TestNG viz., `7.0.0-beta7`

```java
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.Reporter;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.xml.XmlClass;
import org.testng.xml.XmlInclude;

public class ReadMethodParameters {

  @Test
  public void testMethod() {
    ITestResult testResult = Reporter.getCurrentTestResult();
    String value = extractParameterValue(testResult, "Phone");
    String msg =
        String.format(
            "<parameter name='%s' value='%s'/> in Test <%s>",
            "Phone", value, testResult.getTestContext().getName());
    System.err.println(msg);
  }

  private String extractParameterValue(ITestResult testResult, String parameterName) {
    final String methodName = testResult.getMethod().getMethodName();
    XmlClass xmlClass = testResult.getTestClass().getXmlClass();
    List<XmlInclude> includedMethods = xmlClass.getIncludedMethods();
    Optional<XmlInclude> currentMethod =
        includedMethods.stream()
            .filter(xmlInclude -> xmlInclude.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(methodName))
            .findFirst();
    return currentMethod
        .map(
            xmlInclude -> {
              String value = xmlInclude.getAllParameters().get(parameterName);
              if (value == null) {
                value = xmlClass.getLocalParameters().get(parameterName);
              }
              return value;
            })
        .orElse(null);
  }
}
```

Here's how the suite xml file looks like:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="57484602_Suite" verbose="2">
  <test name="57484602_Test_1">
    <classes>
      <class
        name="com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn57484602.ReadMethodParameters">
        <methods>
          <parameter name="Phone" value="iPhone"/>
          <include name="testMethod"/>
        </methods>
      </class>
    </classes>
  </test>  <test name="57484602_Test_2">
    <classes>
      <class
        name="com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn57484602.ReadMethodParameters">
        <methods>
          <parameter name="Phone" value="Samsung"/>
          <include name="testMethod"/>
        </methods>
      </class>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

Here's how the output looks like:

```
...
... TestNG 7.0.0-beta7 by Cédric Beust (cedric@beust.com)
...




<parameter name='Phone' value='iPhone'/> in Test <57484602_Test_1>

<parameter name='Phone' value='Samsung'/> in Test <57484602_Test_2>
PASSED: testMethod

===============================================
    57484602_Test_1
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================

PASSED: testMethod

===============================================
    57484602_Test_2
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================





PASSED: testMethod
PASSED: testMethod

===============================================
    57484602_Test_2
    Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
57484602_Suite
Total tests run: 2, Passes: 2, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================


Process finished with exit code 0
```

**UPDATE**

If you have only one `<test>` tag wherein you have multiple `<class>`  (something like below)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="57484602_Suite" verbose="2">
  <test name="57484602_Test_1">
    <classes>
      <class
        name="com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn57484602.ReadMethodParameters">
        <methods>
          <parameter name="Phone" value="iPhone"/>
          <include name="testIPhone"/>
        </methods>
      </class>
      <class
        name="com.rationaleemotions.stackoverflow.qn57484602.ReadMethodParameters">
        <methods>
          <parameter name="Phone" value="Samsung"/>
          <include name="samsungTest"/>
        </methods>
      </class>
    </classes>
  </test>
</suite>
```

and you would like to read method level parameters then here's how you do it.

```java
  private String extractParameterValue(ITestResult testResult, String parameterName) {
    final String methodName = testResult.getMethod().getMethodName();
    XmlClass xmlClass = testResult.getMethod().getTestClass().getXmlClass();
    List<XmlInclude> includedMethods = xmlClass.getIncludedMethods();
    Optional<XmlInclude> currentMethod =
        includedMethods.stream()
            .filter(xmlInclude -> xmlInclude.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(methodName))
            .findFirst();
    Optional<String> result =
        currentMethod.map(
            xmlInclude -> {
              String value = xmlInclude.getAllParameters().get(parameterName);
              if (value == null) {
                value = xmlClass.getLocalParameters().get(parameterName);
              }
              return value;
            });
    if (result.isPresent()) {
      return result.get();
    }
    String value = "";
    List<XmlClass> classes =
        testResult.getTestContext().getCurrentXmlTest().getClasses().stream()
            .filter(xmlClass1 -> xmlClass1.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(xmlClass.getName()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    for (XmlClass each : classes) {
      value = each.getLocalParameters().get(parameterName);
      if (value != null) {
        break;
      }
    }
    return value;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution and it worked. In your XML I see you have two <test> tags  and I am wondering If there is a way we can get the parameter values from different methods under one test. If you see my XML I have two methods and they have two parameters passed. Just a thought if its a right way to do it?

Comment: @Sammy - I have updated my answer and added that variant as well. Please accept the answer if it helped

Answer (score 0):

Parameters at the `<methods>` level in the TestNG XML is possible and is fairly straightforward.

I've put together an example for your consideration below, but be aware that some items from your original question have been omitted. This is simply for brevity and to highlight the core of the solution.

Starting with the Suite XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Test">
    <test name="Woohoo">
        <classes>
            <class name="com.kroger.ParametersDemo">
                <methods>
                    <include name="testIPhone">
                        <parameter name="phone" value="iPhone"/>
                    </include>
                    <include name="testSamsung">
                        <parameter name="phone" value="Samsung"/>
                    </include>
                </methods>
            </class>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

I've made the assumption that both methods exist on the same class. Note that instead of self-terminating `<include>` tags, we now nest the `<parameters>` as child nodes.

Then, we have our tests:

```
public class ParametersDemo {

    @Test
    @Parameters ({"phone"})
    public void testIPhone(String phone) {
        System.out.println("Phone for iPhone test is: " + phone);
    }

    @Test
    @Parameters ({"phone"})
    public void testSamsung(String phone) {
        System.out.println("Phone for Samsung test is: " + phone);
    }
}
```

With the XML layout in place, we can use the `@Parameters` annotation that we'd use in any other case of consuming XML parameters.

Running the XML, we will get the following output:

```
Phone for iPhone test is: Iphone
Phone for Samsung test is: Samsung
```

Not to take anything away from Krishnan's solution, but I think this will get the job done with a little more simplicity.